# Bootstrap insert div above sticky nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to insert a div above a sticky nav like this example:

http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/ACfflljMW1

However, when I try implement it, it does not seem to work. Is there something obvious I'm missing for this solution to work properly?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

      <head>

      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <title>Title</title>

      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

      <style type="text/css">
         /* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
         .affix {
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
         }

         .affix + .container-fluid {
            padding-top: 70px;
         }
      </style>

  </head>

  <body>
     <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F44336;color:#fff;height:200px;">
    <h1>Bootstrap Affix Example</h1>
    <h3>Fixed (sticky) navbar on scroll</h3>
    <p>Scroll this page to see how the navbar behaves with data-spy="affix".</p>
    <p>The navbar is attached to the top of the page after you have scrolled a specified amount of pixels.</p>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Basic Topnav</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>

      </ul>

  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid" style="height:1000px">
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({placement: function() {
                 if($('.navbar-inverse').hasClass('affix-top')) {
                         console.log("top");                    
                         return 'top';
                  }
                  else {
                      console.log("bottom");
                      return 'bottom';
                  }
              }                
          });
  </script>>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: If the example works, and your implementation does not work, how can we help without seeing your code?

Comment: Some sort of code would help. As of now you are missing everything :)

Comment: The code you posted looks the same as the Codeply which is working.

Comment: This is why I'm a bit confused as well...I don't see why it shouldn't work. So I thought maybe I was missing something obvious :)

Comment: @tinOfBeans bad codeply, try codepen.io or please ur send link web, i can help us.

Comment: @KingRider Codeply is better.. and easier for Bootstrap

Comment: @Skelly hum ok... i know codeply to newbie.

Comment: is anyone able to give it a try and implement it? it could be a silly mistake from my end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after inspecting the errors on Google Chrome, turns out my jquery version was too high.

Use jquery version 1.9 and below 3 and it will work!